# The logo and text are not scrollable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm creating a login screen, and the logo and login text at the top of the screen aren't sliding down; however, the text fields for the username and password below are sliding down. How can I fix this issue?

```
Scaffold(
  body: OrientationBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            UIHelper.getsizedBox(40),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      Constants.loginLogo,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            UIHelper.getsizedBox(60),
            Align(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    Constants.login,
                    style: Constants.loginText(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    Constants.welcomeBackText,
                    style: Constants.welcomeBack(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            UIHelper.getsizedBox(30),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          UIHelper.getUserTextField(),
                          UIHelper.getsizedBox(10),
                          UIHelper.getPasswordTextField(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      Checkbox(
                                        activeColor:
                                            Constants.checkboxActiveColor,
                                        value: isChecked,
                                        onChanged: (bool? value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isChecked = value ?? false;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        Constants.rememberMeText,
                                        style:
                                            Constants.rememberMeTextStyle(),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  InkWell(
                                    child: Text(
                                      Constants.sifremiUnuttumText,
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.amber),
                                    ),
                                    onTap: () {},
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: Constants.loginButtonStyle(),
                                child: Constants.loginButtonTextStyle(),
                              ),
                              UIHelper.getsizedBox(10),
                              Constants.anotherLoginTextStyle(),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    icon: const Icon(Icons.facebook),
                                  ),
                                  IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    icon: Constants.googleLogo,
                                    style: const ButtonStyle(
                                        iconSize:
                                            MaterialStatePropertyAll(30)),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 410,
                                height: 75,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  'images/camp.jpg',
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

I tried wrapping the column structure with SingleChildScrollView and ListView, but it didn't work. I attempted to wrap the column with a SingleChildScrollView. Although I did not receive any errors, the program stopped functioning.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping first column in SingleChildScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making your entire design scrollable, wrap your design with `SingleChildScrollView`.
but there's a question: **is Expansion allowed in scrollable space?**
in another format, can you Expand in `SingleChildScrollView`?

the answer is 'it depends!', *expand widget want all of the available space, where `SingleChildScrollView` provide infinity of available space.*

if you did an exception will be thrown.

so, to solve your problem

1. wrap the root column with `SingleChildScrollView` and **don't expand** within that column.
2. wrap the root column with `SingleChildScrollView` and expand within it but **consider setting** `mainAxisSize` of columns as `MainAxisSize.min` and `Flexible` fit as loose.

by the way, nested scroll views should be avoided specially when they have the same direction.

****************UPDATES****************_______

your code after a bit of refactoring and see the result of the run.

**Notice**: use widgets wisely, (eg: what is the purpose of nested columns), if you can use one and the other one doesn't have a unique goal to achieve remove it.

hope it's a start point to reach your wanted results.

```
Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 40,),

                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'lib/core/assets/images/shopping.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 40,),

                Text(
                  'Login',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Welcome Back',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),

                SizedBox(height: 40,),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),

                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      defaultTextField(controller: TextEditingController(), validator: (s)=>'Error', context: context, label: 'Email', preIcon: Icons.email),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      defaultTextField(controller: TextEditingController(), validator: (s)=>'Error', context: context, label: 'Email', preIcon: Icons.email),

                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Checkbox(
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            onChanged: (v){},
                            value: true,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text(
                            'remember me?',
                          ),
                          Spacer(),

                          InkWell(
                            child: Text(
                              'UnKnown',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.amber),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Login'),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                          minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(Size(double.infinity, 45)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),

                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.facebook),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: Icon(Icons.facebook),

                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Image.asset(
                        'lib/core/assets/images/shopping.png',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    );
```

[image: actual result]

Comment: Would you please review it again?

Comment: @Perfectionist.man see the updates